# how to get host mount path insider docker container

Tags: docker

I would like to get the host mount path from inside docker container. I can only find "docker inspect" commands which can get the information from hosts. Could anyone help on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables if it's just a PATH.

You can write some path infomations in file, map the file into Docker and parse it with docker id.
eg:

```
# docker_id
head -1 /proc/self/cgroup|cut -d/ -f3
>>> ...
{
    "docker_id1": {
        "paths": [
            "/test:/home",
            "/test1:/home1"
        ]
    }
}
```

or use docker inspect file

Or you can cat /proc/mounts in contains inside, it is contains mounts infomations

```
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
shm /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k 0 0
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0  # <-- here
proc /proc/bus proc ro,relatime 0 0
proc /proc/fs proc ro,relatime 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one way could be to pass it as environmental variable when running container.

```
docker run -e HOST_MOUNT_PATH=wanted_path -ti ubuntu:18.04 bash
```

Inside container you can check with

```
echo $HOST_MOUNT_PATH
```